# Algorythm: How to generate 2 slider arrays avoiding repeats

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, sliding-window

Searching for an algorithm, perhaps similar to "sliding window".

```php
// Given that array.
$elementsToShow = ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];

// Generate 2 differents arrays.
$slider1 = ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];
$slider2 = ['B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A'];
```

They will be shown at the same time.

$slider1 starts showing 'A', and will change to its nexts element every 14 seconds.
$slider2 starts showing 'B', and will change to its nexts element every 10 seconds.

After 60 seconds. $slider2 finished its elements and start again from its first 'B' element.

After a while. The element shown in $slider1 and $slider2 will be the same.

How to avoid that?

What I want to know if there is any known algorithm for that or similar...

Having a list of elements (`$elementsToShow`)
Having to "places" where display with different durations "per element".
Generate `$silder1` and `$slider2` in a way that the same element value will never by shown at the same time in the 2 places.

Something like:

```php
// Valid examples.

$slider1 = ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];
$slider2 = ['B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'E'];
$slider2 = ['B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C'];

// Non valid examples.

$slider1 = ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];
$slider2 = ['B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'];
```

Is not a valid solution if the same value is repeated in next position (visually will look like a duration of 20 seconds).

Thank you for reading ;P

**Answering Vivek question:**

The execution will be "simultaneously" but in another place. At this point I only have to generate the arrays (sliders data).

That array will be used in another place I can't touch. So The only thing I am able to do to avoid duplications is build the arrays in a secuence that will not have duplications.

If I draw a "timeline" where Y axis are seconds and in X axis I put First Output and Second Output:

With another example:

```
elements = A,B,C,D,E
First output durations: 2 seconds
Second output duration: 3 seconds
```

```
+----+-----+-----+-------+
|Secs| 1th | 2nd |Problem|
+----+-----+-----+-------+
|  01|  B  |  A  |       |
|  02|  B  |  A  |       |
|  03|  C  |  A  |       |
|  04|  C  |  B  |       |
|  05|  D  |  B  |       |
|  06|  D  |  B  |       |
|  07|  E  |  C  |       |
|  08|  E  |  C  |       |
|  09|  A  |  C  |       |
|  10|  A  |  D  |       |
|  11|  B  |  D  |       |
|  12|  B  |  D  |       |
|  13|  C  |  E  |       |
|  14|  C  |  E  |       |
|  15|  D  |  E  |       |
|  16|  D  |  A  |       |
|  17|  E  |  A  |       |
|  18|  E  |  A  |       |
|  19|  A  |  B  |       |
|  20|  A  |  B  |       |
|  21|  B  |  B  | XXX   |
|  23|  B  |  C  |       |
|  24|  C  |  C  | XXX   |
|  25|  C  |  C  | XXX   |
|  26|  D  |  D  | XXX   |
|  22|  D  |  D  | XXX   |
|  22|  E  |  D  |       |
|  22|  E  |  E  | XXX   |
+----+-----+-----+-------+
```

The XXX is the problem: in the time line when the execution reaches 21,24,25 execution time, the 2 outputs are showing the same values.

I have no way to check in runtime the values going to be shown, so I cannot programatically check when an output goes to change, compare if the value going to be shown is in the other output to "jump" to the next.

Comment: So print characters every 10 seconds one by one?

Comment: hello @vivek_23 Not print... but.... "output". And not every 10 seconds...  There could be for example 2 files or piped outputs expecting "chars" (elements from the array). and in the example. One output will get an element each 10 seconds. And the other output will get an element each 14 seconds. But both outputs cannot have the same element at the same time.

Comment: You want to output simultaneously?

Comment: I will edit and add extra info to answer you ;)